# Shortest algorithm to rotate 2 corners on a Rubik's Cube

Tags: optimization, rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

I'm looking for the shortest algorithm to rotate 2 corners without rearranging any other pieces location or orientation. For example, turning the Top-Front-Right corner clockwise and the Top-Front-Left corner counter-clockwise. My current best is 13 (formerly 16) turns, but would like to learn better if someone can share it.

Comment: There is a way with 14 quarter-turns.

Comment: Great answer below from Florian cutting 2 moves off my version.  However, I was hoping someone had a way that would solve both corners at once rather than a doing one and reversing out to do the other. It there such an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R' D R F D F' U' F D' F' R' D' R U

The idea is to take out a corner from the top layer and put it back with a different rotation.  This can be done in 6 moves (R' D R F D F').  Then you turn the top layer and do the same move backwards.  The move backwards applies the opposite rotation to a different corner and restores the rest of the cube.  Finally turn the top layer back.

Comment: Great answer. I forgot about the front layer since I seldom use it (I am not very coordinated so I avoid turning the front, back, and left sides).

Comment: Same here.  It is the shortest I know in number of moves, but not the fastest to execute for me.

Comment: I got it down to 13 with a little more playing. This one also requires moving the front face (R’ b R2 T’ R2 b’ R’ T R2 B’ F2 B F2).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in **12** moves (HTM) using

U2 R' B D2 B' R U2 R' B D2 B' R

or

U' B2 U L' F2 L U' B2 U L' F2 L

In QTM, 14 moves is optimal.

Found using [Cube Explorer](http://kociemba.org/cube.htm)